# Проблема с git, не могу переключиться на ветку master

Tags: git

Всем привет, суть проблемы в следующем.

Для выполнения задания я должен создать локальную ветку, работать в ней пушить и комитить.
После того как я завершил задание, отправляю его в мастер репозиторий проекта. 
Там уже идет слияние и тд...

После чего я хочу у себя перейти в ветку master, выполнив команду:

```
git checkout master
```

Но, когда я ввожу данную команду, у меня появляется следующее сообщение об ошибке:

```
λ git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
hint: 'master' matched more than one remote tracking branch.
hint: We found 2 remotes with a reference that matched. So we fell back
hint: on trying to resolve the argument as a path, but failed there too!
hint:
hint: If you meant to check out a remote tracking branch on, e.g. 'origin',
hint: you can do so by fully qualifying the name with the --track option:
hint:
hint:     git checkout --track origin/<name>
hint:
hint: If you'd like to always have checkouts of an ambiguous <name> prefer
hint: one remote, e.g. the 'origin' remote, consider setting
hint: checkout.defaultRemote=origin in your config.
```

Буду очень признателен в помощи понять, куда можно двигаться.
Команда:

```
git branch
```

соответственно, мне показывает только текущую мою ветку.
Все комиты по этой ветке завершены и тд.

```
git status
```

Говорит:

```
On branch module3-task1
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Что показывает `git branch -r` ?

Comment: Добрый день!

Вот что дает данная команда:
`
λ git branch -r
  academy/master
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  origin/module1-task1
  origin/module2-task1
  origin/module3-task1
`

Comment: Так вам в строчках `hint:` прямо по пунктам разложено в чём проблема и что делать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А у вас вообще есть эта ветка, master? Судя по ошибке, её не существует.

Для начала, поищите удалённую ветку (в смысле remote, не в смысле deleted) с похожим именем:

```
git branch -a
```

Когда найдёте (скорее всего, это будет origin/master), можете создать локальную:

```
git branch --track master origin/master
git checkout master
```

Ещё есть вот такой вариант (делает то же самое):

```
git checkout master -b origin/master
git branch -u origin/master
```

Comment: Pavel, да когда я ввожу команду :
~~~
git branch -a
~~~
Вижу следующий результат: 
~~~
  remotes/academy/master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/module1-task1
  remotes/origin/module2-task1
  remotes/origin/module3-task1
~~~

Comment: @Alexander ну и?

Comment: Соответственно, я когда ввожу команду 
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
Выдает ошибку:
fatal: the '--set-upstream' option is no longer supported. Please use '--track' or '--set-upstream-to' instead

Comment: Спасибо, поменял команду, как рекомендовала консоль.
 git branch --track master origin/master.

Теперь все хорошо, удалось перейти в ветку мастер.